# How to open file in same directory with c++?

Tags: c++, file-io, directory

Im curently using this code to open the file in the c:\ directory. But I have to place "aimagem.bat" in the directory to work properly.

```
ShellExecute ( 0,"open","C:\\aimagem.bat.",NULL,NULL,SW_NORMAL);
```

Is there a way to open "aimagem.bat" if it's located inside the same folder my project is?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, replace `"C:\\aimagem.bat"` with `"aimagem.bat"` or with `"./aimagem.bat"`

Comment: Relative paths should be avoided when possible. It would be safer to retrieve the calling app's folder, such as by calling `GetModuleFileName()` and then removing everything after the last slash, then append the desired filename to it, and then execute that full path.

Comment: @RemyLebeau hmm.. why is that? why should relative paths be avoided? (Trying to learn something from you)..

Comment: Relative paths can be exploited. All someone has to do is remove the original file and put their own file with a duplicate filename somewhere else on the search path, then you would be opening/executing the wrong file. Very dangerous when executing files especially, since that can lead to malicious code being run. So if you are expecting a file to be in a specific location, open/execute it from that specific location only, don't let the system hunt for the file, because it might find something you don't want.